# print object properties in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a simple Dart file:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
}

void main() {
  var person1 = Person();
  person1.name = 'Rajesh';
  person1.age = 20;
  print("person name $person1.name ");
  print(person1.name);
}
```

I just want to print `print("person name $person1.name ");`, and i want output as `person name Rajesh`. But i am getting output as `person name Instance of 'Person'.name`.

Need some help, i am new to Dart.
`

Comment: you can write `print("person name" + person1.name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
print("person name ${person1.name} ");
```

alternatively you can override `toString` in class:

```
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '''
            person name $name
        ''';
  }
```

then:

```
print(person1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant:

```
print("person name: ${person1.name} ");
```

Remember that you can specify a `toString()` method in the class:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  String toString() => "${name} is ${age} years old"; 
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  String toString() => "${this.name} is ${this.age} years old"; 
}

void main() {
Person person = new Person();
person.name = "John";
person.age = 25;
print(person); // John is 25 years old
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, the error is in the **interpolation string**.
In general, when you use more than one object, you should use the full form of the string interpolation  `${}` rather than just `$`.

For your code, do this instead:

```
print('person name : ${person1.name}');
```

I hope that will be useful to you.